# Ionic2 app moved from mac to pc causing build issues

Tags: node.js, cordova, angular, npm, ionic2

I moved my ionic2 app from mac to windows pc with nodemodules and tried to run using `npm run android`, but getting an error as shown below

[image]

Here is my ionic info:

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.4.0
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.1-201610241941
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.4
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.2
Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.31
OS: Windows 7 SP1
Node Version: v6.2.0
```

I ran following commands:

```
npm uninstall ionic

npm cache clean

npm install -g ionic@latest
```

but still `ionic-app-scripts` is not recognized in my cmd. What am I doing wrong here? It works great in my mac but moving to pc, I'm frustrated.

Any advice would be helpful. Thank you.

Here is [my project repo](https://github.com/darthranjith/ionicdashboard), If I cloned the same app from my repo it's building fine but moving the source code not working.

**Update #1**

Now getting a different error.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried by updating the `ionic-app-scripts` with `npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest`? I'm using the 0.0.38 version (please be aware that in the latest version they switched from rollup to Webpack2)

Comment: Thanks @sebaferreras. but now i'm getting an different error. Please see my updated question.

Comment: Have you seen [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40206774/ionic-2-build-typeerror-cannot-read-property-asseturl-of-undefined)? There they suggest to *take away "^" sign in front of "dependencies" and "devDependencies" in package.json* and then run `npm install` again.

Comment: Thanks @sebaferreras, It works.

Comment: Glad to hear that! :) I've added that as an answer so other SO users can find how to fix the issue easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I add this answer just in case so other SO users with the same issue could find the answer easier. Just like @nyluje recommends in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40206774/ionic-2-build-typeerror-cannot-read-property-asseturl-of-undefined), to fix

> Cannot read property 'AssetUrl' of undefined

you should take away "^" sign in front of "dependencies" and "devDependencies" in package.json, and run `npm install` again.