# *.js.icloud where does that come from in "node_modules" folder or for other files of my project on macOS

Tags: node.js, macos, ionic-framework, npm, node-modules

I use NPM through an IONIC3.0.1 project.

`ionic info` gives:

- Cordova CLI: 6.5.0
- Ionic Framework Version: 3.0.1
- Ionic CLI Version:
  2.2.3
- Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
- Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.12
- ios-deploy version: 1.9.1
- ios-sim version: 5.0.13
- OS: macOS
- Node Version: v6.9.1 Xcode version 9.2

`npm -v` gives: 5.7.1

Sometimes I got in trouble with NPM and the version of the various packages set in the `[project]/package.json` file. I work around it with some `npm install` and altering the [value of the dependencies to the right ones like in that thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40206774/ionic-2-build-typeerror-cannot-read-property-asseturl-of-undefined).

But something new is happening, and has the consequence of throwing errors when building the project.

Some of the files seem to disapear or be renamed. When building `ionic build android` I get the following error:
`Error: Cannot find module './optimize/MergeDuplicateChuncksPlugin`

After a bit of investigation I figure that in `[project]/node_modules` there is a should be the file `webpack/lib/optimize/MergeDuplicateChunksPlugin.js`

But instead   in `[project]/node_moduleswebpack/lib/optimize/`, the file `MergeDuplicateChunksPlugin.js`doesn't exist and it seems to have been substitued by a file `.MergeDuplicateChunksPlugin.js.icloud`.

I don't get it. Is it Apple icloud doing some action on my project?

**NOTE ALSO** that `webpack` is not suppose to be in the list of my `dependencies` in the file `[project]/package.json`.

I've tried to do a remove `rm -rf node_modules/webpack` and reinstall `npm install webpack`.

Remove delete the files but not the structure folder. And the reinstall command `npm install webpack` bugs because there is a file `project/node_modules/.bin/webpack` that should be moved away according to the log also it is not possible to do so.

**My question is: why do I have *.js.icloud files appearing in my project?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that **icloud** process or has processed some operations on some files.

In the **Finder** app go to the folder of the file which appears as missing.

find the `.[file name + its extension].icloud` file, right click to download the correct file. `[file name + its extension]` will become available instead of `.[file name + its extension].icloud`.